# Box around reaction chemmacros

Tags: tcolorbox, chemmacros

I've been trying to use `tcolorbox` to frame a reaction using the reaction environment from `chemmacros`. The use of `\begin{tcolorbox}`and `\end{tcolorbox}` does work:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\chemsetup{modules = all}

\begin{document}

Document starts

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{reaction}
    3 O2 -> 2 O3
\end{reaction}
\end{tcolorbox}

document continues here

\end{document}
```

This produces the document with no errors; however, as expected, the box spans the text width. I want the box to fit the reaction, so I tried to use the `tcbox` command. However, if I put it before the reaction environment, I get a bad math delimiter error and the reaction number appears inside the box, and if I use it inside it won't compile (it says LaTeX error: "kernel/empty-search-pattern" Empty search pattern. For immediate help type H . \end).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently, the error is unrelated to `tcolorbox`, since it occurs with `\fbox` and `\mbox`as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `chemmacros` starts a `reaction` it basically does three things:

- it temporarily sets the `equation` counter to be equal to the `reaction` counter
- it sets the tag form to `reaction`; for this it loads the `mathtools` package because the latter allows easy control of the tag form of an equation.
- it then puts the reaction content inside the formula controlling macro – per default `chemformula`'s `\ch`.

The last point is the problem when you try to use a box macro inside a `reaction`.

But knowing the above we can simulate a `reaction` using `equation` which then allows us to put frames around parts of the content:

```
\begin{equation}
  \refstepcounter{reaction}\usetagform{reaction}
  \ch{...} \tag{\thereaction}
\end{equation}
```

For example using `tcolorbox` and its library `theorems` we can now put a framed box around the content using `\tcboxmath` or `\tcbhighmath` (see the `tcolorbox` manual for details):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = reactions
}

\begin{document}

Document starts
\begin{equation}
  \refstepcounter{reaction}\usetagform{reaction}
  \tcboxmath{\ch{3 O2 -> 2 O3}} \tag{\thereaction}
\end{equation}
document continues here
\begin{equation}
  a + b = c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: please don't start new paragraphs with a math or chemistry display unless it is absolutely necessary…

Comment: It works! Thank you! I was thinking on defining a new "boxed" environment using the reaction counter, but since I don't have that many instances of this I think this is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose this, based on `empheq` (needless to load `amsmath` since it loads `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{exam}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\chemsetup{modules = all}
\newcommand*\widecolorbox[1]{\fboxsep=2ex\fboxrule=1pt\fcolorbox{black}{Gainsboro!40}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

Document starts

%
\begin{empheq}[box =\widecolorbox]{equation}
\ch{
 3 O2 -> 2 O3}
\end{empheq}
%
document continues here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see it works, however, I also use equations that are numbered differently than the reactions (hence why I'm using the reactions module), but this doesn't work with the reactions module by substituting "equation" with "reaction". Am I missing something here?

Comment: I tested first with `reaction`, and it didn't woirk. That's why I used `equation`. You can use a different counter for some equations. There  must be posts on TeX Stack Exchange about how to do that.

Comment: I tried using `\newcounter{react}` followed by
`\newenvironment{react}{\refstepcounter{react}\equation}{\tag{\thereact}\endequation}` and  the environment is not recognized by `empheq`. (Package keyval Error: react undefined. \begin{empheq}[box =\widecolorbox]{react})